# change variable for a target in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile I've a target called `objects` and if I run `make objects` it produces .o from every .cpp. Now I want to introduce a target `check-syntax` that call the target `object` but before change the variable `CFLAGS` from `-Wall -O2` to `-Wall -O0 -fsyntax-only`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(IN GNUMake, anyway, and I'll assume you meant `CFLAGS`)

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2

objects: ...
    whatever

check-syntax: CFLAGS = -Wall -O0 -fsyntax-only

check-syntax: objects
```